XGBoostError: XGBoost Library (libxgboost.so) could not be loaded
Full Error:
[ERROR] XGBoostError: XGBoost Library (libxgboost.so) could not be loaded.
Likely causes:
  * OpenMP runtime is not installed (vcomp140.dll or libgomp-1.dll for Windows, libgomp.so for UNIX-like OSes)
  * You are running 32-bit Python on a 64-bit OS
Error message(s): ['libgomp.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory']

Infrastructure:

AWS Lambda Function

I am importing the XGBoost in the Lambda function and I get above error when I Try to run it.

This error has started when I upgraded the Lambda Function Runtime version from Python 3.6 to Python 3.9

I am importing the XGBoost from the zip I have kept in the S3 bucket and Lambda has a code to import it.

I also tried packaging the libgomp.so.1 with the xgboost zip but that also did not worked.



try using an amazon linux compatible prebuilt wheel
you can using this container as it has same env as lambda
docker run -it --rm amazonlinux:2

in docker container install requirements
make sure to use venv
yum install -y gcc gcc-c++ python3 python3-devel


thanks @exirl for the answer.But this is not working , below are the things i did:


I pulled the amazonlinux and ran container with it also copied my sh file to build the xgboost.zip


Then i installed yum install -y gcc gcc-c++ python3 python3-devel and used venv to install the requirements:



use the correct amazon linux base,
aws python 3.9 runtime is based on Amazon linux 2
so you need to build and package dependencies in the same environment
run the following to start with the correct environment
docker run -it --rm amazonlinux:2

when you are inside the docker container run this
yum update -y
yum install -y gcc gcc-c++ make python3 python3-devel
python3 -m venv /app/venv
source /app/venv/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install xgboost

now do this
find / -name "libgomp.so.1"

Copy this library to your Lambda deployment package
cp /usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1 /app/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/

now zip the deployment package
cd /app/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
zip -r /tmp/xgboost_package.zip .

now upload to S3 and deploy
I tried producing your error, but yeah these things that i mentioned above are fixed
